# How to write a SQL DDL query for a new JPA @ElementCollection

Tags: java, sql, jpa

I have done a code change in a domain class(JPA). I added an ElementCollection to an entity:

```
@ElementCollection(targetClass = String.class)
@CollectionTable(name = "T_NETWORK_STATE", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "NETWORK_ID")})
@Column(name = "STATE")
private Set<String> states = new HashSet<>();
```

Now I want to write a flyway update db script for this change. I need the SQL DDL for the table T_NETWORK_STATE.

I am new to writing sql queries. any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Could you please update your question with details about what you intend to query/update?

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: Okay, understood. So you want to create the collection table?

Comment: @zlas, which underlying database you are having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE T_NETWORK_STATE (
  NETWORK_ID INT,
  STATE VARCHAR(100),
  UNIQUE INDEX (NETWORK_ID, STATE),
  FOREIGN KEY (NETWORK_ID) REFERENCES NETWORK(NETWORK_ID)
);
```

Comment: Thanks @LarsGendner.  Isn't there any constraint?

Comment: @zls there should be, but in your question is no information on the entity containing `states`. I'll take a guess and update my answer, though :-)